# Hadoop 2.5.0 Job not successful,Streaming Command Failed

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, jenkins

**Hadoop version**: Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.1

**mapper and reducer script are shell files**

some parts of printed log:

> AttemptID:attempt_1437751786759_1557_m_007335_0 Timed out after 600 secs
>   2015-08-21 19:46:55,837 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>
> (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1372)) -  map 76% reduce 0%
>   2015-08-21 19:46:57,066 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>
> (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1372)) -  map 100% reduce 100%
>   2015-08-21 19:47:03,159 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>
> (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1372)) -  map 97% reduce 100%
>   2015-08-21 19:47:04,372 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>
> (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1372)) -  map 100% reduce 100%
>   2015-08-21 19:47:04,794 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>
> (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1385)) - Job job_1437751786759_1557 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1437751786759_1557_m_001557
>   Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
>
> 2015-08-21 19:47:04,922 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>
> (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1390)) - Counters: 34
>
> **File System Counters**
>
> FILE: Number of bytes read=0
>
> FILE: Number of bytes written=1415074916
>
> FILE: Number of read operations=0
>
> FILE: Number of large read operations=0
>
> FILE: Number of write operations=0
>
> HDFS: Number of bytes read=501146186
>
> HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
>
> HDFS: Number of read operations=22986
>
> HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
>
> HDFS: Number of write operations=0
>     **Job Counters**
>
> Failed map tasks=1137
>
> Killed map tasks=1483
>
> Launched map tasks=10282
>
> Other local map tasks=10438
>
> Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=10996762530
>
> Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
>
> Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=5498381265
>
> Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=5498381265
>
> Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=5630342415360
>
> **Map-Reduce Framework**
>
> Map input records=7662
>
> Map output records=189860
>
> Map output bytes=8829322
>
> Map output materialized bytes=101153057
>
> Input split bytes=988398
>
> Combine input records=0
>
> Spilled Records=189860
>
> Failed Shuffles=0
>
> Merged Map outputs=0
>
> GC time elapsed (ms)=450437
>
> CPU time spent (ms)=129978840
>
> Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=3951235211264
>
> Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=13755897688064
>
> Total committed heap usage (bytes)=3860902445056
>
> **File Input Format Counters**
>
> Bytes Read=500157788
>
> 2015-08-21 19:47:04,922 ERROR [main] streaming.StreamJob
>
> (StreamJob.java:submitAndMonitorJob(1019)) - Job not successful!
>
> Streaming Command Failed!

**Besides**
In the tracking url,got these logs :

> ++ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
>   + /home/disk1/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop >dfs -D speed.limit.kb=9000 -put ./sites_url hdfs://nameservice1/user/rp->product/dma/newsites/url/ccdb/20150821185246..sites_url
>
> DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
>   Instead use the hdfs command for it.
>
> put: No lease on /user/rp-product/dma/newsites/url/ccdb/20150821185246..sites_url.*COPYING* (inode 913353): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_39002115_1 does not have any open files.
>
> ++ cat sele_url
>
> ++ wc -l
>
> + cn=32
>
> + (( 32>0 ))
>
> + cat sele_url
>
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>
> (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl).
>
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>
> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

**And**  I also find java source code of hadoop [Here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/StreamJob.java.html)

**I searched Google for solutions but failed, and didn't get some useful info from log to guess some possible causes, so I need help or any hints**

**Thank you very much**

**Best regards!**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late, but now I have known what caused this error. In a map, it takes too long to get a response from other service. It means map does not output anything for a long time, so job was killed and then failed